# Implicit conversion of constant literal

Tags: go, type-conversion

In the below code:

```
func main() {

    var a uint8 = 'x'
    fmt.Println(a)
}
```

---

`'x'` is a constant literal (of `untyped rune`)

Does variable declaration for `a` involve implicit conversion of type from `untyped rune` to `uint8`?

Answer (score 3):

The untyped numeric constant `'a'` is implicitly *assigned* a type in the variable declaration.

An `untyped rune` is an untyped numeric constant with default type `rune`.  The default type only comes into play the when constant is used in a context where a type is required.

The [language specification says](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Constants):

> A constant may be given a type explicitly by a constant declaration or conversion, or implicitly when used in a variable declaration

The variable declaration

```
 var a uint8 = 'x'
```

implicitly gives the untyped constant the type `uint8`.  The default type `rune` does not come into play because the context provides a type. There is no conversion involved.

Consider this alternate declaration:

```
var a uint8 = 'ẍ' // Latin Small Letter X with Diaeresis
```

This statement fails to compile with error *cannot use 'ẍ' (untyped rune constant 7821) as the value in variable declaration (overflows)*.  If a conversion was in play, this statement would compile without error.

Comment: I just read this documentation  from [here](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Constants): *An untyped constant has a default type which is the type to which the constant is implicitly converted in contexts where a typed value is required*

Comment: @user1787812 That statement in the specification is not relevant to the question because the context provides the type.

Comment: `f('x')` where `f` is `func f(a uint8)`. Does this involve implicit conversion?